# video hosting provider for medium size business (youtube alternative)

Tags: video, video-streaming, youtube-api, html5-video, vimeo

I wanted to get your recommendations for a video hosting provider.

We need a paid platform to host our videos and embed them into our webpages. Our requirements:

- 1M views per day. 3-5MB per video

  no ads

  doesn't have any branding like Youtube

  API access to post videos

  URL customizations (e.g. instead of youtube.com/myvideo, we'd want it to be ourdomain.com/myvideo)

  videos are viewable on most devices

I saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060020 but it is >3 years old.

Based on my research, vimeo PLUS/PRO won't work for us. Vimeo PRO only allows ~2 million views / year and we can hit it in a couple of days.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Here is a company you can investigate for pro video hosting: http://www.iplayerhd.com/ ...goodluck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brightcove, Kaltura, and Ooyala are probably the top 3 right now in terms of on-demand video hosting and streaming, while Livestream is a good choice if you need to, as the name implies, stream live events. Among the top providers, there aren't a lot of technological differences (other than who they use for their cloud storage, CDN, etc), so it will probably come down to price, customer service, etc. which you'll have to determine based on talking to them all.

We personally prefer Kaltura, because they are friendlier towards open source, which may or may not be philosophically important to your business. All of their code and software is available for free (in all senses of the word) if you want to host it yourself, and they have rock-solid cloud hosting if you want to pay for their SaaS products. Other people I know are perfectly happy with Brightcove as well.

Answer (score 1):

I second iplayerhd.com.  It's < $30/mo, and doesn't limit the number of views.  It does include a monthly bandwidth limit but when we questioned them about it they were willing to up the limit -- it turned out to be high enough that we didn't hit it... hope springs eternal ;-}

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo Pro only has today an upload limit of 20 GB per week (more on demand). However, views and downloads are not limited.
https://vimeo.com/help/faq/vimeo-membership/vimeo-pro